# Tab most recent in jobs not remembered as selected once you manage job alerts

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you perform a search on jobs and you want to view the most recent listings you click **most recent** tab.  However, if you manage your alerts and go back to the search results it resets the tab to matches.  It should maintain the state of the tab you were originally searching on.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Head over to jobs
2. Search for javascript
3. Click the tab **most recent** by default it is matches
4. Click manage my alerts
5. Click << return to job results
6. Here's the issue it resets the search such that you are searching matches rather than most recent

Comment: Good point, but why'd you post it twice? Did I miss something? [Question One](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320047/manage-job-alerts-forgets-what-page-you-are-on-when-you-click-return-to-job-sea)

Comment: @Seth - These are two separate issues, not the same.  As Laura from SO has mentioned, when they are completely different issues, you should post it twice.  The first bug is about the paging system.  The second bug is about the tabbing system.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Looked quite similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. We pass the sort and page parameters to the "manage alerts" URL, so they are set in the "return to job results" link.